# Is it possible to to rewrite the base URL in Sinatra? 

Tags: ruby, url, sinatra, rack, radix

Is it possible to to rewrite the base URL?

E.g. instead of `www.host.com/` to use `www.host.com/blah/` as 
a base url and so:

```
get '/' do
  ...
end
```

would work for `www.host.com/blah/`

I could append to all my routes `'/blah/..'` but any gems etc.
would fail to work as well.

This can be done in Rails easily and I would like to have it in Sinatra as well.

Comment: What gems are you using that do redirects?

Comment: sinatra-authentication. Basically I am also running sinatra through CGI and that complicated stuff as well. It has to be a more pretty solution. I was thinking of using the before and after filters.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do: you should be able to write your app so it's independent of the base url, e.g. using the [`url` helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Generating%20URLs). Then the path to the app is determined by how you set up your server, not the Sinatra app itself. Gems should work okay with this too.

Comment: Let me clarify then. I am working on a server for which I have not complete access over. I have been assigned a directory for which I can work with my project over CGI.  

So instead of receiving '/' for the get in sinatra I receive 'foo/blah/'. 

'/about' becomes '/foo/blah/about' etc. 

kfl62 suggested something good, which I have seen already, but any gems that redirect to '/login' would fail as they would redirect to www.host.com/login instead of www.host.com/foo/blah/login

Comment: Does setting `enable :prefixed_redirects` help?

Comment: I edited my answer with some examples. I still believe something like: `rewrite %r{/}, '/foo/blah'` will solve your problem.

Comment: @matt should have submitted his response as an answer. I found it very helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a rack middleware for this [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) and I am quite happy with it :)

```
    use Rack::Rewrite do
      rewrite %r{^/\w{2}/utils}, '/utils'
      rewrite %r{^/\w{2}/ctrl},  '/ctrl'
      rewrite %r{^/\w{2}/},      '/'
    end
```

EDIT:

Not sure if I understand your problem, but here are a `config.ru` file

```
# encoding: utf-8
require './config/trst_conf'
require 'rack-flash'
require 'rack/rewrite'

use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => 'zsdgryst34kkufklfSwsqwess'
use Rack::Flash
use Rack::Rewrite do
  rewrite %r{^/\w{2}/auth},  '/auth'
  rewrite %r{^/\w{2}/utils}, '/utils'
  rewrite %r{^/\w{2}/srv},   '/srv'
  rewrite %r{^/\w{2}/},      '/'
end

map '/auth' do
  run TrstAuth.new
end
map '/utils' do
  run TrstUtils.new
end
map '/srv' do
  map '/tsk' do
     run TrstSysTsk.new
  end
  map '/' do
    run TrstSys.new
  end
end
map '/' do
  run TrstPub.new
end
```

and an example Sinatra::Base subclass

```
# encoding: utf-8

class TrstAuth < Sinatra::Base

  # Render stylesheets
  get '/stylesheets/:name.css' do
    content_type 'text/css', :charset => 'utf-8'
    sass :"stylesheets/#{params[:name]}", Compass.sass_engine_options
  end

  # Render login screen
  get '/login' do
    haml :"/trst_auth/login", :layout => request.xhr? ? false : :'layouts/trst_pub'
  end

  # Authentication
  post '/login' do
    if user = TrstUser.authenticate(params[:login_name], params[:password])
      session[:user] = user.id
      session[:tasks] = user.daily_tasks
      flash[:msg] = {:msg => {:txt => I18n.t('trst_auth.login_msg'), :class => "info"}}.to_json
      redirect "#{lang_path}/srv"
    else
      flash[:msg] = {:msg => {:txt => I18n.t('trst_auth.login_err'), :class => "error"}}.to_json
      redirect "#{lang_path}/"
    end
  end

  # Logout
  get '/logout' do
    session[:user] = nil
    session[:daily_tasks] = nil
    flash[:msg] = {:msg => {:txt => I18n.t('trst_auth.logout_msg'), :class => "info"}}.to_json
    redirect "#{lang_path}/"
  end

end
```

maybe this helps :) [full source on github](https://github.com/kfl62/trst_sys_sinatra).

Comment: Thanks for this, I already came upon this but any redirects to '/login' etc see my comment above would fail. I am going to use this if I can not find anything better and rewrite the code of any gems :)

Answer (score 2):

In a `before` block you can edit `env['PATH_INFO`]`; Sinatra will then use the edited value for routing.

For your example, something like this might work...

```
before do
    env['PATH_INFO'].sub!(/^\/blah/, '')
end
```

I agree with the other answers that using a middleware component is a more robust solution but if you want something concise and simple, that works *inside* the Sinatra app instead of via `config.ru`, then munging the Rack environment is not bad.

Comment: For anyone else looking for this, I just added a similar solution for Apache + CGI / FastCGI with RewriteEngine here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52689478/823617

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at https://github.com/josh/rack-mount, maybe that one can help you out?

Comment: Hmm thanks for this but this wouldn't work if a gem would redirect to '/' right?