# Setting up Sinatra to run in a subdirectory

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra

Now I am pretty new to Sinatra/Ruby/Apache but have inherited a Sinatra application to deploy.

Currently Apache is set up to run from a document root (httpdocs) and I need to run a ruby application underneath a folder subdirectory such as: /httpdocs/webapp

What do I need to do to get this up and running under a subdirectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link might be helpful, it explains how to deploy a Sinatra app with Apache using Passenger (mod_rack):
[Deploying a Sinatra App with Apache and Phusion Passenger](http://www.pastbedti.me/2009/11/deploying-a-sinatra-app-with-apache-and-phusion-passenger-a-k-a-mod_rack/)

The part of particular interest to you is the `RackBaseURI` option in the virtual host configuration. The official documentation is available here:
[Phusion Passenger users guide - Deploying Rack to Sub URI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri)

Comment: Got it. But the apps in the subdirectory are pointing '/' to the parent application. How can I it be pointed to the root of each app?

Comment: goo: if I understand your problem correctly, any url references generated by a sinatra app in a subdirectory are not taking the base url included the subdirectory name into account. if this is the problem, you can look at a gem like: [sinatra-url-for](https://github.com/emk/sinatra-url-for/) or create a helper as suggested in this discussion [get absolute base url in sinatra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950234/get-absolute-base-url-in-sinatra)

Comment: goo: As @brentvatne says you should always use an URL helper - since Sinatra 1.2.0 there's a [helper included](http://www.sinatrarb.com/2011/03/03/sinatra-1.2.0.html#url_helper). Additionally I had weird results because I specified the Apache `RackBaseURI` option inside of the `Directory` directive in the Apache configuration, also it seems to be important to use the symlink method described in the article @brentvatne linked.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue. Since there was no answer here for how to do this without Passenger, I'm going to document the solution for Apache + CGI or FastCGI.

The trick is to rewrite `PATH_INFO` for Rack, and everything will fall into place:

1. Set up `.htaccess`:

   ```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sinatra_app.cgi [QSA,L,E=PATHINFO:/$1]
   ```
2. In your Sinatra code, before anything else:

   ```
    ENV['PATH_INFO'] = ENV['REDIRECT_PATHINFO']
   ```

Now all URLs like `/subfolder/resource/123` will hit the correct route in the Sinatra app.
In the above case `get '/resource/:id'` will work correctly, assuming the Sinatra app was put into `/subfolder`.